# Is there an image format that supports alpha-transparency and animation. While being supported by most browsers?

Tags: image, animation, graphics, gimp, image-formats

Is there an image format that supports alpha-transparency and animation.  While being supported by most browsers?  I have found only one image format, but it was not supported by any web browsers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402633/what-alternatives-for-animated-gifs-are-there

Comment: I have .apng add-on for GIMP, but it is not browser supported yet.

Comment: .apng is only supported by Firefox, it has the most promise of any format I've seen.  Are there any others?

Answer (score 1):

No.

There is  `.mng` (Multi-image Network Graphics), which is partially supported by GIMP - enough support to create
GIF like animations with alpha transparency - but far from [.mng's full capabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple-image_Network_Graphics), and I know of no browser which implements MNG animation support (haven't tried either)

And, as people say in the comments, there is "APNG", which is supported by Firefox alone,
but not supported natively in GIMP.

If you really need this, I'd say the better way to go is to use some Javascript to compose a .png slideshow.