# What is the most compressed animated image type HTML can display?

Tags: html

I've been working with the Cordova framework the last few days and actually created something I'm very proud of, however the application size is sitting at 15MB. I know that's not all that much, but when over half of it is coming from a single .gif file, that's bothersome.

The background for my applications login screen is 10.3MB in .GIF format.

I'm wondering if HTML supports any other formats that can be compressed more, without losing quality. That.. does not require a video player.

Comment: How long is the GIF (how many seconds it takes before it repeats) ?

Comment: Is the video available by link to view?  GIF has its place for small automated cartoon like images. MP4 is good with stuff that has more movement and colors gradients like videos.

Comment: AFAIK HTML does not require browsers to support any image type. Browsers support the types they want. I think GIF is the only widely supported type which can contain animations, but you can also try [MNG](http://www.libpng.org/pub/mng/spec/) or [APNG](https://wiki.mozilla.org/APNG_Specification). And the compression ratio can vary with the image, there is no best type.

Answer (score 0):

I researched a bit and I think this might answer your question, which 'may' make this question a duplicate, but I'm leaning away from. It's from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402633/what-alternatives-for-animated-gifs-are-there) question. Just keep in mind that browser nuances are a big variable when it comes to this as they don't all support the same thing.

> Animated png or APNG (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG). They can be
>   made in GIMP with the APNG Plug-in But animated Gif's really are the
>   main one out there - flash kinda took over though, but that isn't
>   really an image per se.
>
> Also, other alternatives from the same wikipedia page: The MNG file
>   format is a more powerful alternative to APNG, although is a more
>   complex format and has less web browser support.
>
> The GIF file format has better application and browser support than
>   APNG, but it is limited to 256 colors per frame and supports only 1
>   bit alpha transparency, by mapping one of the palette colors to
>   transparent.
>
> SVG combined with scripting or SMIL can animate vector graphics and
>   can incorporate raster graphics. (See SVG animation.)
>
> Dynamic graphics created with HTML 5 canvas Object can also be
>   animated.
>
> An alternative method for animations in web pages is to use
>   conventional static images and animate them using JavaScript,[22]
>   Adobe Flash, Microsoft Silverlight, Java or other plugin based
>   technologies. - Nathan

Another alternative, within the same question, is this:

> WebP is an image format employing both lossy and lossless compression.
>   It is currently developed by Google.
>
> Advantages of animated WebP compared to animated GIF
>
> WebP supports 24-bit RGB color with an 8-bit alpha channel, compared
>   to GIF's 8-bit color and 1-bit alpha.
>
> WebP supports both lossy and lossless compression; in fact, a single
>   animation can combine lossy and lossless frames. GIF only supports
>   lossless compression. WebP's lossy compression techniques are
>   well-suited to animated images created from real-world videos, an
>   increasingly popular source of animated images.
>
> WebP requires fewer bytes than GIF1. Animated GIFs converted to lossy
>   WebPs are 64% smaller, while lossless WebPs are 19% smaller. This is
>   especially important on mobile networks.
>
> WebP takes less time to decode in the presence of seeking. In Blink,
>   scrolling or changing tabs can hide and show images, resulting in
>   animations being paused and then skipped forward to a different point.
>   Excessive CPU usage that results in animations dropping frames can
>   also require the decoder to seek forward in the animation. In these
>   scenarios, animated WebP takes 0.57x as much total decode time2 as
>   GIF, resulting in less jank during scrolling and faster recovery from
>   CPU utilization spikes.
>
> Disadvantages of animated WebP compared to animated GIF
>
> In the absence of seeking, straight-line decoding of WebP is more
>   CPU-intensive than GIF. Lossy WebP takes 2.2x as much decode time as
>   GIF, while lossless WebP takes 1.5x as much.
>
> WebP support is not nearly as widespread as GIF support, which is
>   effectively universal.
>
> Adding WebP support to browsers increases the code footprint and
>   attack surface. In Blink this is approximately 1500 additional lines
>   of code (including the WebP demux library and Blink-side WebP image
>   decoder). Note that this problem could be reduced in the future if
>   WebP and WebM share more common decoding code, or if WebP's
>   capabilities are subsumed in WebM's.
>
> https://developers.google.com/speed/webp  - Vladimir