# HTML 5 transparent video

Tags: jquery, html

I have a video with transparent background. Whenever a try to play it on a html page using video tag in html5 i get a black background instead of my html5 background. Any solution?

Comment: i remember this site: http://www.notthesa.me/. I'll check it out for an answer now, but it doesn't load. :) if it does for you, you can check it out yourself.

Comment: also you should delete jquery tag.

Comment: check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073303/can-i-have-a-video-with-transparent-background-using-html5-video-tag

Comment: try adding style "display:none;". this has transparent video with html5 video tag: http://jakearchibald.com/scratch/alphavid/

Comment: What video format are you using that supports transparent background? [Not mp4, I surmise.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055962/how-to-create-an-h264-video-with-an-alpha-channel-for-use-with-html5-canvas). Note that in the duplicate question the highest-rated answer is wrong. To my knowledge you cannot have a video with alpha in HTML5.

Comment: @IsmetAlkan See the link I just posted. That demo isn't a transparent video, it's a video that has a separate grayscale region (not channel) which is used to frame-by-frame manually set alpha values in an HTML5 canvas.